# TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE] for Algolia with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am following the Firebase tutorial on how to implement Algolia with Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

I am currently stuck on the indexing part of the tutorial as I have errors coming from the firebase cloud-functions logs.

The error is: **TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "x-algolia-api-key"**

How can I fix this error?

Here is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");

const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app_id;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.api_key;
const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;

const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'users';
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

// Update the search index every time a blog post is written.
exports.onUserCreated = functions.firestore.document('path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // Get the note document
    const user = snap.data();
  
    // Add an 'objectID' field which Algolia requires
    user.objectID = snap.id;
    console.log(user.objectID)
  
    // Write to the algolia index
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    return index.saveObject(user);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your `ALGOLIA_ID` or `ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY` value is undefined.
You try to use values from functions environment configuration but it does not seem to be there.

**In terminal** go to your firebase project folder and type

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

You should see the output that should look like JSON object. If you don't see `algolia` settings, set it like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set algolia.app_id="YOUR APP ID" algolia.api_key="YOUR API KEY" algolia.search_key="YOUR SEARCH KEY"
```

More info here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: I do get this output{
  "algolia": {
    "key": "ADMIN_API_KEY",
    "app": "YOUR_APP_ID"
  }
} but what do I do then?

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing .app_id to .app on line 5 but I get another error which says "onUserCreated - undefined"

Comment: @EliasFizesan consider asking another question relative to your new problem. This error looks like an issue in your code and not relevant to firestore settings.